# swift3 - print array index to each row

Tags: swift3, tableview

how do you print out the `index` of an array to a tableview cell?

for example:

```
var list = [Person]()
```

I have this array of objects and I add each object to the tableview like so:

```
cell.nameLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row].firstName + " , " + list[indexPath.row].lastName
```

but I also want to print the `index` for each item next to the first and last name. For example, if the array has `["mike jones", "James smith"]`, it would look like this:

1    mike jones

2    James smith

it would be stored in this `positionLabel`

```
//cell.positionLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let person = list[indexPath.row]
cell.nameLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row) \(person.firstName) \(person.lastName)"
```